# Apache Ant property value with interperter

Tags: ant

Why can't I set property like this in Apache Ant?

```
<property name="checker" value="php ${basedir}/vendor/code-checker/src/cc.php" />
```

And then exec it like this

```
<exec executable="${checker}">
    <arg value="-d" />
    <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
</exec>
```

Instead I have to specify whole path with that scripts' interpreter each time I want to use that checker

```
<exec executable="php">
    <arg value="vendor/code-checker/src/cc.php" />
    <arg value="-d" />
    <arg path="${basedir}/src" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *either* use `executable` for the executable you want to run (`php` in this case) and `arg` for its arguments, *or* you can specify the command and all its arguments in a single space-separated attribute

```
<exec command="${checker} -d ${basedir}/src"/>
```

You can't mix and match the two.  And note that the `command` form will not work if the `basedir` contains spaces.  If there's any chance of an individual argument containing spaces then there's no choice, you *must* use the `executable` and `arg` form.

Comment: I don't want to exec the script right away, instead I want to save it like an `alias` in `.bashrc` and use it later in multiple `target`s just by specifying the `${checker}`. Couldn't that be done in my case somehow?

Comment: @meridius yes, you can, as I've shown in my example, but you have to use the `command` version for all your exec calls and `${basedir}` must not contain any spaces. If you can't guarantee that then you have to split all the arguments up individually.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to define the `<exec />`, instead I want to define the `<property />`. The `<property />` will just create the "link" I can later use in multiple `<exec />`s. The `<exec />` will immediately execute the `command`/`executable` and I don't want that. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @meridius look again at my example. You _can_ define a property `checker` and then say `<exec command="${checker} some arguments"/>` in one place and `<exec command="${checker} different arguments"/>` somewhere else. The caveat being that this won't work if any of the arguments needs to contain embedded spaces.

Comment: Ok, but then the defined property would just look like this `<property name="php" value="php" />` which would serve me no purpose. What I need is to define property `<property name="checker" value="php checker.php" />` which I would then use on several places with different arguments. But when I do that, the Ant will fail with `Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "php .../code-checker.php": error=2` as in nonexisting file or directory. If you know how to bypass this, please post the complete working example, otherwise it seems we won't be able to understand each other.

Comment: @meridius no, the point I've been making is that if you use the `command` approach then you _can_ have `<property name="checker" value="php checker.php"/>` and use `<exec command="${checker} -d ${basedir}/src"/>`.  But only if `basedir` does not contain spaces.  If you want to allow `basedir` to contain spaces then what you want to do is not possible - you can't mix and match, it's either `command` (which does its own argument splitting on whitespace) _or_ `executable` with `arg`s, which does no word splitting at all.